# Ampere's Law and Circulation?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

[image]

The net circulation should be zero if the net current is zero. However, I don't see how the circulation in the Amperian loop above can be zero. All the lines interact the loop only once and all their circulation contributions are positive or negative depending on the assumed direction of integration.

Could someone explain how the net circulation would be zero? Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the problem set up some more? Is the system shown in the picture supposed to be 2d or 3d? What does a current have to do with it? You didn't label the arrows. I would think the arrows must be current, but you said the current is zero.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs Sure. The picture is 3d and the arrows are the magnetic field lines. They intersect the edge of an Amperian loop at an angle. By current I mean the net current flowing through the Amperian surface (as specified by Ampere's Law)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circulation is indeed zero. You are confusing flux and circulation.

In Ampere's law, you consider the quantity $\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}$ around the bounding path $C$. You do not consider the flux $\int \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$ over the surface bounded by $C$.

In your example, it looks like $\vec{B} \perp d\vec{l}$ everywhere.

Comment: That question (v1) was like a rorschach test, but I think you go the right interpretation. Good job +1.

Comment: Thanks! The field isn't perpendicular to the loop - the arrows are tilted towards the loop so that they are at an angle. In this case the circulation isn't zero is it?

Comment: right. In this case the circulation isn't zero, so there must be a current passing through the surface (assuming steady currents and charge distributions).